# mysql join to eliminate duplicates

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a table 'sharelist' with the following fields:

```
  senderID
  recipientID
  senderComment
  recipientComment
  viewed
  linkID
```

All fields are ints.

Each entry in the table represents an item that was shared between two users.

linkID is what is being shared between the two users.

senderID is the ID of the user who initiated the sharing, and the opposite is true for recipientID.

senderComment is the number of comments that were written by the sender and have yet to be seen by the recipient. The opposite is true for recipientComment.

viewed is 0 if the recipient has not viewed the shared item yet, 1 otherwise.

I have to find all linkID's that are considered new with respect to user X. This means that one of three things is true

1) senderID = X and recipientComment!=0 (There are comments that user X has not seen about a linkID he shared with someone else)

2) recipientID = X and senderComment!=0 (There are comments that user X has not seen about a linkID that someone else shared with him)

3) recipientID = X and viewed=0 (There is a linkID that someone sent to user X, which user X has not seen)

In addition, because a user can share the same linkID with multiple people, there will be multiple entries with the same linkID. the query must return only one row for a given linkID. The following query achieves this

```
SELECT S.linkID
FROM sharelist S
WHERE (S.senderID=:userID AND S.recipientComment!=0) 
OR (S.recipientID=:userID AND S.senderComment!=0) 
OR (S.recipientID=:userID AND S.viewed=0) 
GROUP BY S.linkID
```

However, I would like to modify this query such that all entries that do not fit the three requirements would come afterwards. So basically the query would return a list where the top half are "new" and the bottom half are "not new". Help me stackoverflow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using expressions in the ORDER BY; something along the lines of:

```
  SELECT S.linkID
    FROM sharelist S
   WHERE (S.senderID=:userID OR S.recipientID=:userID) 
GROUP BY S.linkID
ORDER BY SUM(S.recipientID=:userID AND S.viewed=0) DESC,
         SUM(S.recipientID=:userID AND S.senderComment!=0) DESC,
         SUM(S.senderID=:userID AND S.recipientComment!=0) DESC,
         SUM(S.recipientID=:userID) DESC,
         SUM(S.senderID=:userID) DESC
```

**UPDATE**

Sorry, I forgot about the GROUP BY in the original query.. you will need to aggregate the results in the ORDER BY expressions, see above.

Expressions in ORDER BY once resolved work the same as column values, `SUM`ming a condition returns the number of rows for which that condition is true (true = 1, false = 0 in this case).

The query first gets all sharelist rows WHERE the user is the sender or recipient and groups them by linkID.. they are ordered as follows in order:

- By the count of rows where the user is the recipient and has not viewed the share DESC.
- By the count of rows where the user is the recipient and has not viewed a sender comment DESC.
- By the count of rows where the user is the sender and has not viewed a recipient comment DESC.
- By the count of rows where the user is the recipient DESC.
- By the count of rows where the user is the sender DESC.

Note if two linkID groups match on the first condition count then they will be ordered by the second condition count, if they match again, third count... and so on.
DESC means the higher counts come first.

I would keep the last line now that we are counting rows.

I have also guessed at the order that you want your linkIDs to be returned.. but you can muck around with it as you see fit!

Comment: The query is not working as intended and I can't find a pattern in the results that would point to the bug. Could you explain how the boolean expressions in the order by clause work, and then I could investigate further?

Comment: @Nate, Sorry it was late and I missed the GROUP BY! I have added an explanation of sorts.. see update!

Comment: When you use the SUM function, does it operate over the set of rows that are combined into entry by the GROUP BY?

Comment: @Nate Yep, that's the badger!